# How to run ajax script code inside @foreach loop in laravel view?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, foreach

I try to run the script for every @foreach loop like in the code below. But it seems the script only work only for the first loop.
How to make it run for every loop ?

```
@foreach ($list as $e)
   @section('js')
                <script type="text/javascript">
                                            
                function a(){
                                                
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '{{ url("get-topik/") }}/{{ $e->id }}'
                        })
                        .done(function(data) {
            
                        var html="";
                           for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                              html += '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-sm badge-primary" style="background-color: #51b3f9">'+data[i].get_topik.topik+'</span>'
            
                          }
                     $("#topik").append(html)
                       });
                    }
                                                
    
                a();
        
            </script>
            @endsection

       <span id="topik">
                            
        </span>

@endforeach
```

Thanks Before :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this script? This script does not run when the template is rendering. You're basically trying to define *n* functions, all of them called `a()`, which cannot be done.

Comment: What i hoping is a() function run as many as the foreach loop with different $e-id @El_Vanja

Comment: You must understand that the scripts do not execute in the `foreach`. Learn about [client and server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming). What you're doing here is creating a new script tag, each of them defining their own function `a()` to be executed after the template is rendered, on page load. And you can't have multiple functions with the same name. You don't need AJAX here at all, you can directly insert the data you're fetching.

Comment: Welcome to SO... Making ajax requests in a loop is never a good idea or a good design. For your case, I can suggest that you should get the topik for each item of the $list in the same controller method where you are getting the $list and then send that data to view. It will not only be efficient saving multiple network requests but also less messy design

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            
    function a(id, url){
                                    
            $.ajax({
                url: url + id
            })
            .done(function(data) {

            var html="";
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    html += '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-sm badge-primary" style="background-color: #51b3f9">'+data[i].get_topik.topik+'</span>'

                }
            $("#topik-" + id).append(html)
            });
    }
                                    

    
</script>
        

@foreach ($list as $e)
   
       <span id="topik-{{$e-id}}">
                            
        </span>
        <script> a( {{$e->id}}, {{ url("get-topik/") }} ) </script>

@endforeach
```

Otherwise, I don't think this is the best approach to achieve what you want to do, Have you tried to do it only with laravel instead of mixing with ajax?

Comment: i try that code. But why a() function is not defined